# Linq FirstOrDefault returning multiple

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a strange issue in which a linq statement is returning multiple entities even though it has `.FirstOrDefault()`.

```
var endlog = from e in endLogs
             where e.user_id == log.user_id && e.end_time <= log.start_time
             group e by e.end_time into g
             select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.end_time).FirstOrDefault();

user_state_log eLog = endlog.SingleOrDefault();
```

What this is doing is selecting the log with the most recent end time compared to the supplied `log`.
I get an exception on `user_state_log eLog = endlog.SingleOrDefault()` stating that there is more than one entity in the variable. Any ideas?

Comment: The type of `endLogs`/`e` is?

Comment: Need parentheses around the entire statement before FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you mean to use `group e by` instead of `orderby`? There is a chance that the grouping will contain multiple entities.

Answer (score 1):

Your `FirstOrDefault` is applying to the result of `select`, which occurs once for every group (`g`). I believe the result is every value in `endlog` will be a single item rather than a group.

You might have intended for the `FirstOrDefault` to apply to the query rather than the projection (`select`):

```
var endlog = (from e in endLogs
             where e.user_id == log.user_id && e.end_time <= log.start_time
             group e by e.end_time into g
             select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.end_time)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It was a combination between your's and @DreamBuildLabs answer that was able to fix it. I needed `orderby` but also needed the parentheses.